# lucene & multiple related entities

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have 3 entities like:

```
USER                GROUP              PERMISSIONS
id                  id                 id
name                ...                name
...                                    ...
group_id                               group_id
```

I want to search for USER entites but with the name of a PERMISSION entity (i.e. if the user types a name of a PERMISSION then all the users should be enlisted that have that PERMISSION via the GROUP entity)

I have a solution how to connect 2 entities (using indexEmbedded and containedIn) but no clue what to do when there are 3 entities.

Could somebody help please?

Thanks, V.

---

### UPDATE

I have to follow the changes in the Permission entity so I use the containedIn too. I have a NullPointerException when using the following code.

```
    indexedMapping
    .property("groups", ElementType.METHOD)
    .indexEmbedded()
    .prefix("group.")
    .targetElement(Group.class);


    super.entity(Group.class)
    .indexed()
    .indexName("Group_Index")
    .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
    .field()
    .property("user", ElementType.FIELD)
    .containedIn()

    .property("permission", ElementType.METHOD)
    .indexEmbedded()
    .prefix("permission.")
    .targetElement(Permission.class);


    super.entity(Permission.class)
    .indexed()
    .indexName("Permission_Index")

    .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
    .field()
    .store(Store.YES)

    .property("groups", ElementType.METHOD)
    .containedIn();
```

And the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.updateContainedInMaxDepth(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:641)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.updateContainedInMaxDepths(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:602)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain the `indexedEmbedded`. Use `indexedEmbedded` on `user.group` **and** on `group.permission`. Then the property `user.group.permissions.name` will be automatically added to the `User` index.

Note that, if I remember correctly, the `Group` and `Permission` entities have to be indexed (`@Indexed` annotation or programmatic API equivalent) for this (especially the `containedIn`) to work, even if you don't query the `Group` or `Permission` indices explicitely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a the reply! I updated my original post would it be possible for you to have a look at it please? Thanks!

Comment: @Viktor It might be worth posting a second question. Please provide in particular environment information such as Hibenate version, Hibernate Search version, JDK version, and some context about your programmatic mapping. I wonder why there are mentions of "super", in particular...